# Does the UK Consulate in New York send confirmation emails?

Tags: visas, uk, applications

Hey guys I have sent my documents to the UK consulate, new York, after my biometrics and one of my friends told me that there will be an email from the consulate that they have received my documents, Does anybody know if this is true? It has been 3 days, and I didn't get that email. However when I tracked my mail using the given tracking ID, it says delivered at New York and that someone collected it.
Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: @K Reny Susan Where did you get your biometrics done? You should receive an automated ‘no reply’ acknowledgement email from UKVI in New York once your application is logged in their system.